# downgrade to rails 2.3 from 3.1.1[how to]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to install redmine1.4 for that need to have my rails version2.3, but I have rails3 .
How can I downgrade my rails version -> **Rails 2.3.14**. Thanks

Comment: Is there anything wrong when installing rails2?

Comment: Dumb question, but why are you installing an old version of redmine?

Comment: Yeah,is the latest version of redmine is stable ?

Comment: Very much so. http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Download   2.0.3 (2012-06-18)

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

Comment: I need to instal "CRM" and "invoicing" plug-in which only supports redmine1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I not sure I get the question. From what I understand you want to install Redmine which requires rails 2.3.x but you have rails 3 gem installed. I'm not familar with redmine but I think it should use bundler and simple `bundle install` should do the trick.

If not, the simplest solution would be to uninstall rails 3 gem and install rails 2.3.x gem. For that you need to:

```
$ gem uninstall rails
$ gem install rails --version "2.3.14"
```

However this may broke your other apps which use rails 3.x ver. Thus I recommend using one of following tools for managing ruby versions and use feature called **gemsets**:

- [RVM](https://rvm.io/)
- [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for stopping by and answering to this . Its really helpful . Hi5 :)

Comment: R3 use bundler, so I doubt installing R2 will break any R3 applications. Bundler effectively replaces RVM when it comes to gems (Ruby version is another story). Just use `bundle --path`.